# Reusabilidade do Control

Tags: mvc

Me deparei com a seguinte frase usando MVC:

> "(...) the View and Controller objects are specifically written to each type of interface (and technology), and are generally not reusable between interfaces."
>
> ---
>
> "(...) os objetos de View e Controller são escritos especificamente para cada tipo de interface (e tecnologia), e na maioria dos casos não são reutilizáveis entre interfaces diferentes."

O *Control* é reutilizável ou depende da linguagem?

[Fonte](http://alvinalexander.com/uml/model-view-controller-mvc-definitions-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O *Control* é reutilizável ou depende da linguagem?**

Depende do código. Vou te explicar falando sobre o termo **Reutilização de código**, também chamado de **reutilização de software**, que é o uso de software existente, ou do conhecimento de software, para a construção de um novo software.

**Reutilização de software**

O termo reutilização de software significa você poder reusar partes de sistema que você já desenvolveu. Nesse contexto se encaixa, especificações, módulos arquitetura e código fonte. Apesar da reutilização está relacionada ao aumento dos níveis de qualidade e produtividade, reaproveitar um código não é simples. Isso porque, você precisa criar "trechos" que podem ser reutilizados. Por exemplo, um modelo de site com os menus "Home, Quem somos, Contato".

**Reusabilidade no MVC**

A ideia central por trás do MVC é reuso de código e separação de conceitos. Ele busca organizar o projeto de uma maneira que facilite a reusabilidade e manutenção, e bons frameworks que utilizam o padrão MVC irão melhorar ainda mais esta capacidade.

Na camada de `Model`, ficam as classes que fazem a comunicação com o Banco de Dados, representando estas informações. A camada `View` então vai exibir os novos dados do Model ao usuário. A camada de `Controller` é responsável por gerenciar eventos e acionar as classes de modelo para realizar alterações nas informações.

Ao utilizar o padrão, alterações ficam contidas nas suas camadas, ou afetam o mínimo possível outras camadas. O fluxo MVC vária de acordo com a implementação de cada framework, no entanto geralmente ele segue o esquema:

- O usuário interage com a interface
- O controlador gerencia os eventos da interface, invocando uma ação apropriada
- O modelo é notificado da ação, alterando o estado do modelo
- A visão é notificada da alteração e é atualizada

Referências:

- [Reusabilidade](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/pat/reusabilidade.html)
- [Reutilização de software](https://www.devmedia.com.br/reutilizacao-de-software-revista-engenharia-de-software-magazine-39/21956)
- [Reuso de software](https://administradores.com.br/artigos/reuso-de-software-algumas-vantagens)
- [Boas práticas com MVC](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/pt-br/basics.best-practices)
- [MVC](https://brizeno.wordpress.com/tag/model-view-controller/)

Answer (score 1):

A *Controller* geralmente é dependente da linguagem/tecnologia utilizada pela *View* e *Model*, por isso se você muda a forma como as duas se comunicam com o *Controller*, vai dificultar uma reutilização do mesmo. Vou tentar deixar mais claro com um exemplo simples:

Digamos que temos uma aplicação web semelhante ao Twitter ou Facebook, onde listamos postagens de uma ou mais pessoas relacionadas a um usuário. E de acordo com que ele vai descendo a barra de rolagem da página, mais posts são carregados dinamicamente.

Vamos nomear aqui nossos componentes MVC:

#### View

Como estamos em desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, podemos dizer que nossa *View*, ou seja os componentes com os quais o usuário consegue interagir, é nossa marcação (HTML).

---

#### Controller

Mais uma vez, por estarmos trabalhando com uma aplicação web, o componente que fará o intermédio entre nossa *View* e nosso *Model* será uma linguagem de script suportada pelo browser, muito provavelmente Javascript.

---

#### Model

Nosso *Model* é um serviço escrito em qualquer linguagem de servidor, com o qual nos comunicamos via HTTP. Esse serviço é responsável pela lógica de negócio da aplicação. No nosso caso ele nos retornará os posts de pessoas relacionadas ao usuário que está utilizando nossa aplicação.

---

Agora que temos nossa aplicação desenhada e sabemos as responsabilidades das tecnologias, vemos claramente o que vai acontecer quando o usuário usar a barra de rolagem:

- Nosso *Controller* vai ser ativado pelo evento de `scroll` do browser.
- Nosso *Controller* vai então pegar as informações necessárias para fazer uma requisição HTTP para nosso serviço. (Provavelmente via ajax, que é um recurso oferecido pela maioria dos browsers para executarmos requisições HTTP sem recarregar a página.)
- Nosso *Model* vai receber a requisição, aplicar a lógica de negócio e retornar para nosso *Controller*.
- Nosso *Controller* vai atualizar nossa *View* com as informações do *Model*.

Agora imagine que temos que fazer uma aplicação com o mesmo comportamento, utilizando o mesmo serviço (*Model*) só que agora para Desktop, ou Mobile. Quais componentes teríamos que mudar na nossa aplicação atual?

A maioria dos Desktops ou Mobiles oferecem recursos para utilizar o protocolo HTTP, isso quer dizer que podemos nos comunicar com nosso modelo de qualquer plataforma, ou seja ele permanece inalterado. Mas nem todas oferecem um interpretador de Javascript ou leior de HTML. Então vamos ter que adaptar a *View* e *Controller* para as novas plataformas/tecnologias.

Esse é um tipo de aplicação que é comum não ocorrer reutilização do *Controller* porque a plataforma com a qual o usuário irá interagir muda.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

É difícil reutilizar Views e Controllers. Geralmente eles estão acoplados a tecnologia. Vou dar exemplos com tecnologias Microsoft que utilizo. Não é uma resposta muito técnica, mas espero que ajude.

**Reutilização de Model**

Eu posso criar um Model em C# ou VB.NET que eu consiga utilizar em uma solução ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET WebForms, WPF e Windows Forms. Basta eu criar esse model num projeto Class Library. Eu poderia utilizar um model feito em Delphi por exemplo com `DllImport`, assim como outra tecnologia pode usar esse model se eu compilar para interoperabilidade e essa tecnologia for capaz de consumir DLLs.

**Controller**

Agora meu Controller no ASP.NET MVC irá herdar de `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. Meu controlador em WPF deveria ser algo totalmente diferente que saiba nada sobre `System.Web. Não consigo aproveitar o controlador.

O Controller faz o intermédio entre a `View` e `Model`. Para isso ele deve utilizar artefatos diferentes para recuperar dados da View: O controllador do ASP.NET deve ser capaz de gerenciar protocolos HTTP, POSTS, GETS etc para ler dados View.

**Frameworks**

Por exemplo se eu criar um Model em CodeIgniter(PHP), um model que estenda `CI_Model`, eu não vou ser capaz de utilizar esse model em outra aplicação PHP sem o CodeIgniter instalado. Gerei aqui um acoplamento ao framework. O que eu quero dizer, que reutilização de código não é algo tão simples assim.